# How to show Google FAQ structured data when there are quick navigation href=#XXX and id=XXX

Tags: html, seo, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm using valid FAQ structured data for some of my pages and it works fine on all pages which don't have quick navigation menu (page jumps with `href=#XXX` and `id=XXX`). For those with quick navigation the search result shows the quick navigation menu instead.

How should I make the FAQ SD with higher priority?

Comment: In my humble opinion, a productive answer to this question is impossible without an analysis of your markup for structured data and the source code of the web page.

Comment: @nikant25 you are right. If you search on google.com for 'live dealer online' it will show you the top result. The web page is livedealers[dot]com here is a screenshot - https://prnt.sc/p6on7u As you see that search result includes #page jumps, but the page also has FAQ SD, which i'd like to have instead of the quick links.

Answer (score 0):

**[The homepage has structured data](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livedealers.com%2F)** with multi top-level types ***Question***. Each of these types is embedded in the property **[mainEntity](https://schema.org/mainEntity)**. This way your data has multi properties **mainEntity**.

Check the value of this property from the documentation of Schema:

> Indicates the **primary entity** described in some page or other
>   CreativeWork.

In my humble opinion, the phrase "**primary entity**" means that this property should be the only one in the data of the web page. This my opinion is confirmed by the following example from the **[Google guide for the type FAQ](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage)** (**[link of the example](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=jsonld&utm_source=faq-page)**):

```js
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "What is the return policy?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Most unopened items in new condition and returned within <strong>90 days</strong> will receive a refund or exchange. Some items have a modified return policy noted on the receipt or packing slip. Items that are opened or damaged or do not have a receipt may be denied a refund or exchange. Items purchased online or in-store may be returned to any store.<br /><p>Online purchases may be returned via a major parcel carrier. <a href='http://example.com/returns'> Click here </a> to initiate a return.</p>"
    }
  }, {
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "How long does it take to process a refund?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "We will reimburse you for returned items in the same way you paid for them. For example, any amounts deducted from a gift card will be credited back to a gift card. For returns by mail, once we receive your return, we will process it within 4–5 business days. It may take up to 7 days after we process the return to reflect in your account, depending on your financial institution's processing time."
    }
  }, {
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "What is the policy for late/non-delivery of items ordered online?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Our local teams work diligently to make sure that your order arrives on time, within our normal delivery hours of 9AM to 8PM in the recipient's time zone. During  busy holiday periods like Christmas, Valentine's and Mother's Day, we may extend our delivery hours before 9AM and after 8PM to ensure that all gifts are delivered on time. If for any reason your gift does not arrive on time, our dedicated Customer Service agents will do everything they can to help successfully resolve your issue. <br/> <p><a href='https://example.com/orders/'>Click here</a> to complete the form with your order-related question(s).</p>"
    }
  }, {
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "When will my credit card be charged?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "We'll attempt to securely charge your credit card at the point of purchase online. If there's a problem, you'll be notified on the spot and prompted to use another card. Once we receive verification of sufficient funds, your payment will be completed and transferred securely to us. Your account will be charged in 24 to 48 hours."
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

In this example, you can see that all questions are embedded in only one property **mainEntity**.

This example is in JSON-LD format which you can convert to microdata (as it is in your data) using this free tool online **[RDF Translator](https://rdf-translator.appspot.com/)**.

However, I dare say that the microdata format has a rather strong dependence on the source code in which this data is installed. **[The homepage of your website has invalid HTML and critical errors such as Duplicate ID](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.livedealers.com%2F)**. Check the **[following information from W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#syntax-errors)**:

> **Syntax error**s: Certain invalid syntax constructs, when parsed, result
>   in DOM trees that are highly unintuitive. Sometimes it **is really hard
>   to pick up the structured data when the HTML is broken completely**.

This invalid HTMLL may interfere with **[web page rendering](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model)**.

Comment: I'm using the same approach for FAQ SD on other pages, where it works just fine. For example on page livedealers[dot]com/blackjack you can see that it shows the FAQ list on searching - https://prnt.sc/p9ud5i